# asp.net mvc viewdata display in a viewpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewdata

I sent a viewdata to a view page like this.

```
 public ActionResult SelectRes(int id)
    {
        var ResList = resrepository.GetAll();
        ViewData["ResList"] = new SelectList(ResList, "ResId", "Res_KORNM");

        return View(svcresrelationRepository.GetAll());
    }



@foreach (var item in ViewData["ResList"] as List<ITSDapper.Dapper.Resource>)
        {
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center;">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(a=> item.Res_KORNM)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

And I tried to display the viewdata in a view page but it's not worked.
(Object reference not set to an instance of an object)

How display the viewdata in foreach statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are converting reference to wrong type, you are creating `SelectList` instance while in View you  are convering it to `IList<T>`, you should convert it to `SelectList`:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewData["ResList"] as SelectList)
        {
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center;">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(a=> item.Text)  // note this as well
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You would typically use a `SelectList` for data that is to be selected by a user.

If this is the intention you can just use an `Html.DropDownList`:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedId", 
                         (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["ResList"])
```

If you are simply needing to view the data, I would change your server-side code to use something other than a `SelectList`.

This could be done as follows:

**Controller**

```
 public ActionResult SelectRes(int id)
    {
        var ResList = resrepository.GetAll();

        ViewData["ResList"] = ResList;

        return View(svcresrelationRepository.GetAll());
    }
```

**View**

```
@foreach (var item in ViewData["ResList"] as List<ITSDapper.Dapper.Resource>)
        {
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center;">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(a=> item.Res_KORNM)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

Comment: the point is he is converting reference to wrong type, from current code it is not clear he wants a dropdown or not?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Doesn't make sense to generate a SelectList for data from server-side though surely? Simply making the code compile is not the best answer.

Comment: @ hutchonoid : You're right. I misused the expression from used  a dropdownlist. I should wrote like that;

Comment: @Roy At least your sorted now. :)